# MongoServer does not contain a definition for 'Create'

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am getting the MongoServer does not contain a definition for 'Create' exception while compiling the below code. Please help me on this.

Libraries and versions

- MongoDB.Bson 2.0.0
- MongoDB.Driver 2.0.0
- MongoDB.Driver.Core 2.0.0

```
List<Info> names = new List<Info>();
String name = "";
MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
MongoDatabase myDB = server.GetDatabase("ES");
MongoCollection<Info> Persons = myDB.GetCollection<Info>("MyCollection");
foreach (Info Aperson in Persons.FindAll())
{
    name = name + " " + Aperson.Name;
    names.Add(Aperson);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `MongoServer.Create()` method was removed in [version 2.0](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoServer.htm).  It has been deprecated since at least [version 1.7](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.7/html/be930ec9-1678-e9b0-df2d-655be96a3747.htm).

Instead, use [`MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient.htm).  To get access to the `MongoServer`, use [`MongoClient.GetServer()`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClientExtensions_GetServer.htm)

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need to do, using the new [MongoDB.Driver 2.0:](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/)

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];

var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase("ES");  

var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollection");
var persons = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
```

See more at: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-20-net-driver

Regards.